# Creating a Conditional Numerical List of Features in Python

Tags: python, pandas, list, list-comprehension, any

I am trying to create a numerical index list that pulls from a list of columns given that any string in a feature list is contained in the name of those columns.

I have attempted to use a list comprehension with conditional statements. However, the code gives me a Type Error "in  requires string as left operand, not bool".

```
import pandas as pd
feature_list = ['a', 'b']

x = pd.DataFrame({"data_a":[1,2,3], "data_b":[1,2,3], "data_c":[1,2,3]})

numerical_index_list = [x.columns.get_loc(a) for a in [b for b in list(x.columns) if any(c for c in feature_list) in b]]
```

Would anybody be able to help me get a conditional list comprehension that will give me a list of columns that contain the strings a and b ["data_a", "data_b"]?

Comment: The problem code is here: `if any(c for c in feature_list) in b`. `any()` returns either `True` or `False`, and Python is complaining that it can't find that in `b`

Comment: @darthbith what would be the proper way to use a conditional statement to get the result I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `feature_list` as a `set` and see if that and the column name intersect. This seems to be the approach you're trying for; although I believe this is faulty as the word **data** has a in it therefore all pass that test.

```
features = set(feature_list)
cols = x.columns
[cols.get_loc(c) for c in cols if features.intersection(c)]
#[0, 1, 2]
```

Maybe use a better method of determining if column is a subset of `feature_list`? Something like `if c[-1] in features`? This way only the first 2 pass and the last won't as c isn't in `feature_list`.

```
[cols.get_loc(c) for c in cols if c[-1] in feature_list]
#[0, 1]
```

Or **more relevant to your comment** just remove `"data_"` from the column name and use the first method.

```
[cols.get_loc(c) for c in cols if features.intersection('_'.join(c.split('_')[1:]))]
#[0, 1]
```

Comment: The trouble with the last bit of code is that the actual columns contain more than just one letter. So for example data_revenuestream or data_cash.

Comment: Just use `'_'.join(c.split('_')[1:])` to remove the `data_` entirely.

Comment: Edited my answer to include that

Comment: that just gave me an empty list